# Inject animation function into transition with mixin

Tags: string, animation, split, sass

What I have:

```
.test{
  @include transition("all .5s");
}

$animationFn: "ease-in-out";
@mixin transition($transition){
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: unquote($transition) unquote($animationFn);
}
```

This would generate:

```
.test{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Which is fine. However, I also have the case where I want to name multiple transitions, for example:

```
.test{
  @include transition("font-size .5s, color .5s");
}
```

What I would expect in this case:

```
.test{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: font-size .5s ease-in-out, color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

What is necessary in my mixin to make it work with multiple transition statements, divided by a comma? Or in other words: How to inject the animation function before `,` and `;` inside `transition` in this mixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.
You want to use [Sass' @each directive](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while), combined with [variable arguments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Variable_Arguments) and [Sass' append function](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/).

**Step by step:**

`@mixin transition($transitions...){` This tells Sass you're accepting a varying quantity of arguments. The catch is to separate your different transitions with a comma, which differs a bit from what you're doing now.

`$result : ();` creates an empty list.

`@each ...` : we're iterating over your list of transitions.

`$result : append($result, ..., comma);` we're appending the interpolated string (`unquote(...) unquote(...)`) to `$result`, comma separated, and assigning it to `$result`.

`transition : $result;` we're using the interpolated string.

**Code snippet:**

```css
$animationFn: "ease-in-out";
@mixin transition($transitions...){
  $result : ();
  @each $transition in $transitions{
    $result : append($result, unquote($transition) unquote($animationFn),comma);
  }
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: $result;
}

.test{
  @include transition("all .5s");
}

.test2{
  @include transition("font-size .5s", "color .5s");
}
```

**Edit: support optional animation function**

By using the [`@if`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#if) directive, you can test if the argument is empty.
Because variables arguments have to be the last ones, however, you must move the optional argument to the beginning.
Since there's no way to test if the first argument is a part of the list or the optional argument, you have to always provide a first argument for the animation function (it is not optional). If you want to keep the default one, however, just pass an empty string.

```css
$defaultAnimationFn: "ease-in-out";
@mixin transition($animationFn, $transitions...){
  @if $animationFn == "" {
    $animationFn : $defaultAnimationFn;
  }

  $result : ();
  @each $transition in $transitions{
    $result : append($result, unquote($transition) unquote($animationFn),comma);
  }

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: $result;
}

.test{
  @include transition("","all .5s");
}

.test2{
  @include transition("linear","font-size .5s", "color .5s");
}
```

**Edit 2: added another way to map different animation functions to different transitions**

This version leverages Sass' lists. You create a list of animation function and another list of transitions unto which apply these functions.
Here, the limitation is that you need to provide the exact same numbers of elements in each list.
However, you get to compose your transitions and animation functions the way you want.
Empty strings default to a default animation function (defined outside the scope of the mixin).
We could be a bit more defensive and add more tests and branching for edge cases. As long as you know what you're doing, it shouldn't be that necessary though.

```css
$defaultAnimationFn : "ease-in-out";

@mixin transitionMap($animationList, $transitionList){
  $result : ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($animationList) {
    $animationFn : nth($animationList, $i);
    @if $animationFn == "" {
      $animationFn : $defaultAnimationFn;
    }
    $result: append($result, unquote(nth($transitionList, $i)) unquote($animationFn) , comma);
  }

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: $result;
}

.test3{
  $myAnimationsList : "ease-in", "linear", "";
  $myTransitionsList : "font-size .5s", "color .5s", "width .5s";
  @include transitionMap($myAnimationsList,$myTransitionsList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I will award the bounty as soon as it's possible (after 10 hours). However, I have one question regarding this mixing that you can probably answer: Is there a chance to make the animation function optionally with a parameter too? So, the default value would be `$animationFn`, but it would be possible to specify a custom function as the last function parameter, e.g. `@include transition("font-size .5s", "color .5s", "ease");`?

Comment: I just added another snippet. You need to provide the `animation function` as the first argument, even if it's empty, though.

Comment: I just added a third way of doing it.